# Crop Video temporary on runtime/Online

Tags: .net, video, video-streaming, video-processing

I am in need of **Video Player**, or **Software** or **API** or any other idea for that help me to save the storage issue. 
Let me explain, I have a video file about `300mb` which contains 10 clips if i make video in parts each part is of size around `20mb` so in total i will have `11 files` and `500mb` and it sucks because i have video files in thousands, So is their any video player or software by which i can crop/split video online so it don't affect my server space and also i don't have to handle a lot of videos with original video file and its sub-files.

In best of knowledge the better way is I have to take a video and just take particular part from the video during run-time by telling its frame/time range and play it. So in this case i will not get headache of file-system again and storage issue also.

Can anyone suggest me something or any better idea please?

Comment: Can you clarify the issue: Is the problem that you just don't have enough space to store the thousands of videos? Why is splitting the videos up necessary anyway? Have you considered compressing the videos or uploading them to a streaming service - assuming you wish to deliver them online?

Comment: Yes, one of major issue is of space. And can you please elaborate about "compressing the videos" and "streaming service". May be your idea works better. Thanks

Comment: From your original description and comment, I understand (1.) that you have thousands of video files that you are trying to upload somewhere, (2.) that you concerned about a storage space limitation, and (3.) you want to split the videos into shorter segments so that there will be multiple smaller files. Past this, you will need to clarify your original question. Where are you trying to upload the videos to? Why do you need to split them up into parts, or to make the files smaller? What storage limitations are you trying to work with?